# can't get latexmk to work in TeXShop

Tags: glossaries, mac, texshop, latexmk

I'm trying to add a glossary to my book.  I wanted to use `latexmk` to execute `makeglossaries` for me.  I'm using TeXShop on my Mac.

So I went to the TeX Live Utility and activated the `latexmk` package.  Then I went to my source document and put the following on the top line:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
```

Then I typeset my document.  As best I can tell, adding that line to the top had no effect.  It's not automatically running `BibTeX`, it's not creating my glossary (I already put all the relevant glossary commands in), etc.

What have I failed to do?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9):

You need to make TeXShop see the `latexmk` Engine.  Go to your `~/Library/TeXShop` folder, and inside you will see an `Engines` folder.  Inside there should be a bunch of `*.engine` files, and a folder named Inactive.  Move the `pdflatexmk.engine` file (and any of the other `*mk.engine` files if you wish) from the Inactive folder to the Engines folder.

You will need to restart TeXShop for the change to take effect.  Now, when you use the pulldown Typeset menu, the `pdflatexmk` engine should show up, and also your `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk` line should work.

Comment: Thanks—that worked great!  Somehow I had assumed that making a package active in the TexLive Utility would take care of this, but it didn't.

Comment: @Mike  Accepting answer (by clicking on the checkmark) is a preferred way of saying Thanks. For more details on [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 3):

An update, after the passage of 8 years:

First, based on information provided by Herb Schulz[1] via email, the recommended format is

`% !TEX program = pdflatexmk`.

Second, to add "engines" to TeXShop's relevant menu, use the procedure described by @Alan Munn per the information in TeXShop's embedded documentation folder:

Menu bar —> TeXShop —> Open ~/Library/TeXShop

Then open that folder's file Engines/Inactive/Latexmk/Latexmk For TeXShop.pdf, where Alan's procedure is described. See also Herb Schulz's *Using latexmk with TEXShop*.

These notes have been confirmed on Mac OS 11.1, with TeX Live 2020 and TeXShop 4.58.

[1]: herbs at-sign wideopenwest dot com

Comment: Where can I find Herb Schulz's *Using latexmk with TEXShop*?