# How to enable --shell-escape when using pdflatexmk?

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, shell-escape, auto-pst-pdf

I want to use the `auto-pst-pdf` package and therefore I need the `--shell-escape` option to be enabled. I did this in my TeXShop preferences as follows:

[image]

However when I use `pdflatexmk` (by writing `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk` on the first line) to compile my document the option is not taken into account and `auto-pst-pdf` can not be used.
How do I enable the `--shell-escape` command with `pdflatexmk`?

I use TeXShop 3.24 on Mac OSX with pdflatexmk version 4.37.

Comment: Related [can't get latexmk to work in TeXShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127788/15717) and [all-in-one-engine for TeXShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41271/15717)

Comment: The `pdflatexmk` works fine without the `auto-pst-pdf` package as this does not require the `--shell-escape` option. As far as I can tell the related questions are about getting `latexmk` to work basically, but I already have that working.

Comment: use as command `pdflatexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S" `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigate to your `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` folder and duplicate the file `pdflatexmk.engine` to, say, `pdflatexmk-shell.engine`. Then open this file with TeXShop itself and add the `-pdflatex="pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S"` option: here's how the file should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TSBIN="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk"
export LTMKBIN="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk"
export LTMKEDIT="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin"
# make sure latexmkrcedit exists in bin
if [ ! -e "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" ] ; then
    cp "${LTMKBIN}/latexmkrcDONTedit" "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit"
fi
"${LTMKBIN}"/latexmk -pdf -r "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" -r "${TSBIN}/pdflatexmkrc" -pdflatex="pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S" "$1"
```

Now, if you start your document with

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk-shell
```

the shell escape will be enabled.

Here's a copy of the console when a file with that magic line is processed:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 2 July 2013, version: 4.37.
**** Report bugs etc to John Collins <collins at phys.psu.edu>. ****
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'bart.pdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex --shell-escape  -recorder  "bart.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bart.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./bart.aux)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./bart.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on bart.pdf (1 page, 11541 bytes).
Transcript written on bart.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'bart.pdf'
Latexmk: All targets (bart.pdf) are up-to-date
```

The lines

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 \write18 enabled.
```

are the proof that shell escape is enabled.

Comment: How can I duplicate the file pdflatexmk.engine? Plus, what is the full name of the file? is it a .text file? What is it?

Comment: @user65526 The file is in `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`. If you select the file, you can duplicate it from the menu or with Command-D, then change its name. It's a text file, you can open it for editing also with TeXShop itself.

Comment: What do you mean by 'select' the file?

Comment: @user65526 Single click on it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to other automation tools, I would highly recommend  [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara). Integration with `TeXShop` (which I assumed is your chosen IDE) and any other editor is easy and is covered in the documentation.

To enable `--shell-escape` you simply give the directive

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it looks like a powerful tool. However I'm looking for a quick way to use `psfrag` with `pdflatexmk` and using a whole new tool for this sounds like overkill to me.