# How to use pdfx with latexmk?

Tags: latexmk, pdfx

Is there a way to use the really nice way to produce latex-pdfs using latexmk in combination with the packages pdfx to produce pdf-A documents?

When I run following simple code on my Mac Texlive2013 (TexShop Editor) with Latexmk 4.31 I run into troubles. There are no problems when I process it simply with Latex
Here my example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}    % PDFA-Type A
\begin{document}
 This is a test

\end{document}
```

Here the error:

```
> Latexmk: applying rule 'latex'... This is pdfTeX, Version
> 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)  restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode (./Test2.tex LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> Babel <3.9f>
> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
> (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
> Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
> (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/pdfx.sty
> (./Test2.xmpdata)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xmpincl/xmpincl.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
> 
> Package xmpincl Warning: Only pdflatex is supported by the xmpincl
> package.
> 
> ) /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/pdfx.sty:137:
> pdfTeX error (\ pdfobj): not allowed in DVI mode (\pdfoutput <= 0).
> l.137  \immediate\pdfobj
>                          stream attr{/N 4}  file{sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm} No pages of output. Transcript written on Test2.log. Latexmk: Log file
> says no output from latex Latexmk: For rule 'latex', no output was
> made Failure to make 'Test2.dvi' Collected error summary (may
> duplicate other messages):   latex: Command for 'latex' gave return
> code 256 Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing.
> Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Any suggestion to solve that problem?

Comment: It seems you're calling `latexmk` for DVI output and not PDF. Try the `pdflatexmk` engine.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I was missing the pdflatexmk engine. Problem solved!

For the case of a Mac this can be installed according to following instruction: [can't get latexmk to work in TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127788/cant-get-latexmk-to-work-in-texshop)