# TeXShop: order of typesetting for bibliography and glossary

Tags: compiling

I've explored other questions but they seem to involve coding. I'm looking specifically for the order of options in the drop-down menu (no coding).

I have TeXShop version 4.44 for Mac, which has a typesetting drop-down menu. For example, when I need to include a bibliography, this is the order of typesetting I use:

```
1. LaTeX
2. BibTeX
3. LaTeX
4. LaTeX
```

My options in the drop-down menu are as follows:

[image]

I now need to incoporate a glossary into my final PDF. What order of compilation should I use? I've tried several orderings including `pdflatexmk`, but it hasn't worked yet.

EDIT in response to a comment:

In my main file, I have:

```
\usepackage{glossaries}

%Make the glossary - following 3 commands.
\loadglsentries{gloss}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{} %Gets rid of the period after the glossary definition, I think.
\makeglossaries 

\loadglsentries{glossary_file}
```

After loading some other files, I have:

```
% GLOSSARY
% _________

%The \printglossaries command indicates the glossary.

\chapter*{GLOSSARY}
%Print the glossary
\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossary]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps the following related question might help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127788/cant-get-latexmk-to-work-in-texshop

Comment: What package are you using for the glossary? Are you using a custom extension for you glossary files?

Comment: @HerbSchulz please see the edit?

Comment: Hmmm... At first glance I see no reason why using TeXShop's pdflatexmk engine didn't complete the full run and create the final output. Please place the the TeXShop directive line `% !TEX program = pdflatexmk` at the top of your file and typeset using Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T). Let me see the Console output if that doesn't work.

Comment: The output the second time was: Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 18 June 2019, version: 4.65. Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date

Comment: @HerbSchulz The glossary still does not appear.

Comment: Please try to clean up all auxiliary files and typeset again. Also it would be helpful if you showed the complete Console output.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I resolved the issue: the tex file I was inputing had all of the \gls commands removed, and of course the glossary doesn't show up if there are no items referenced in the main text. Ugh. Thank you for the help.